# Statement lambda can be replaced with expression lambda

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, lambda, option-type

I do user and invitation validation using the Optional facility

```
@DeleteMapping("/friends/{username}")
public
HttpEntity<Boolean> removeFriend(
        @ApiParam(value = "The user's name", required = true) @PathVariable String username
) {
    Long fromId = authorizationService.getUserId();

    return userService.findByUsername(username)
            .map(user -> {
                 return friendshipService.findFriendship(fromId, user.getId())
                        .map(friendship -> {
                            friendshipService.removeFriendship(friendship);

                            friendship.setToId(friendship.getFromId());
                            friendship.setFromId(friendship.getToId());

                            friendshipService.removeFriendship(friendship);

                            return ResponseEntity.ok(true);
                        }).orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
            }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User not found"));
```

However, `IntelliJ` is colouring my grey `return`, But when I remove the `return`, it highlights to me that there is no `return`.

Could someone explain how it works and what is it all about?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Your *statement lambda*

```
param -> { return expression; }
```

can be changed to an *expression lambda*:

```
param -> expression
```

Simple, isn't it? Note, that the curly brackets and the semicolon need to be removed.

Comment: Works. Thanks. Which in your opinion is a better way to lambda this https://pastebin.com/imEtjwHp or this https://pastebin.com/gcaUMYQ4?

Comment: There is no _better_ in this context. Do it as you like. But for me, both code snippets are not readable. This should always be the first criterion for coding.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose would you mind giving us an example for the readable code snippets?

Answer (score 5):

> Sometimes I found useful to leave the
>   braces where they are if the block of code is long enough (I think it improves readability)

In Android Studio you can locally disable the warning using `//noinspection CodeBlock2Expr` at the start of the method like in the example below

```
//noinspection CodeBlock2Expr
button.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
        //a long single method call...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Statement lambda can be replaced with expression lambda` message appears when we use curly braces "`{}`" and semicolons "`;`" in expression lambdas for implementing functional interfaces. We can do away with those in such a situation. That being said, I personally feel it is a good coding practice to use block lambdas even for single line functional interface implementations, the way we do it for single line `for` and `while` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Reports lambda expressions with code block bodies when expression-style bodies can be used instead. The result of the conversion is shorter and more clear.

Example:

```
Comparable<String> c = o -> {return 0;};
```

After the quick-fix is applied:

```
Comparable<String> c = o -> 0;
```